# Can I change how titlesec prioritizes padding values?

Tags: titlesec

I've run into a situation in a document where I sometimes have a section heading that follows directly after a subsection heading with no generic paragraph content inbetween. In these cases the value I set using `\titleformat` for padding before section headings seems to be ignored in favor of the value set for after subsection headings. See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*6}{*1}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*2}{*0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Test
\section*{Section heading}
\subsection*{Subsection heading}
\section*{Another section heading(note lack of padding above)}
Test
\section*{Yet another section heading}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of MWE missing padding]

Normally I do not want any space at all after the subsection headings, but in the case of a subsection->section transition in the document I would like to prioritize the use of the padding value I set for section headers. Is there a way this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the `largestsep` option to titlesec. The default is `aftersep`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[largestsep]{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*6}{*1}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*2}{*0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Test
\section*{Section heading}
\subsection*{Subsection heading}
\section*{Another section heading(note lack of padding above)}
Test
\section*{Yet another section heading}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh `largestsep` where have you been all my life?!